# df.set_index() on datetime objects list column for future dates not working.

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

```
d = {'one':[datetime.datetime(3000, 6, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0),], 'two':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df
df = df.set_index(['one'])
print df



ERROR: At

df = df.set_index(['one'])

ValueError: Unable to convert [datetime.datetime(3000, 6, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0) atetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0)  datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0)] to datetime dtype
```

But it is working very much fine with dates within years as 2000-2999.

Not sure what is the issue here. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

- Venkat

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations), pandas `Timestamp` objects can only reach to the year 2262. However, [the documentation also describes a way around this limitation.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans)

The idea is that if you don't need the nanosecond resolution of the `datetime64` dtype, you can use a `PeriodIndex` to achieve the desired result.

In your case, it looks like you might want something along the lines of:

```
s = pd.Series([30000601, 20160601, 20160701, 20160501])
def conv(x):
    return pd.Period(year = x // 10000, month = x//100 % 100, day = x%100, freq='D')
span = pd.PeriodIndex(s.apply(conv))
df.index = span
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code raises different Exceptions (a `SyntaxError`, a `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` and a `pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds` error) for me but I think the last one, the `OutOfBoundsDatetime` refers to the same problem you are seeing.

When building a DataFrame from data which contains date-like objects, the dates are converted to NumPy `datetime64[ns]` dtype. For instance,

```
import datetime as DT
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[DT.datetime(2000, 6, 1, 0, 0), DT.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0), DT.datetime(2016, 7, 1, 0, 0), DT.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0),], 'two':[1,2,3,4]})

print(df.info())
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
# Data columns (total 2 columns):
# one    4 non-null datetime64[ns]    # <-- Notice the dtype
# two    4 non-null int64
# dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
# memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

At the moment, `datetime64[ns]` is the [only NumPy datetime64 data type supported](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7307) by Pandas. [The range of dates](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units) this datatype can represent is `[1678 AD, 2262 AD]`. Hence, an exception occurs when the `datetime.datetime` object refers to a date outside this range.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working.

```
s = pd.Series([30000601, 20160601, 20160701, 20160501])
def conv(x):
    return pd.Period(year = x // 10000, month = x//100 % 100, day = x%100,     freq='D')
span = pd.PeriodIndex(s.apply(conv))
df.index = span
```

Thank you for the help.